# How does the HTTP protocol work exactly?

Tags: http, qt, sockets, header, connection

I thought I had this all figured out, but now that I'm writing a webserver, something is not quite working right.

The app listens on a port for incoming requests, and when it receives one, it reads everything up to the sequence "\r\n\r\n". (Because that signifies the end of the headers - yes, I am ignoring possible POST data.)

Now, after it reads that far, it writes to the socket the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n
Content-type: text/html\r\n
Content-length: 6\r\n
\r\n
Hello!
```

However, when Firefox or Chrome tries to view the page, it won't display. Chrome informs me:

> Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): Unknown error.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Here is some of the code:

```
QTcpSocket * pSocket = m_server->nextPendingConnection();

// Loop thru the request until \r\n\r\n is found
while(pSocket->waitForReadyRead())
{
    QByteArray data = pSocket->readAll();

    if(data.contains("\r\n\r\n"))
        break;
}

pSocket->write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");

QString error_str = "Hello world!";

pSocket->write("Host: localhost:8081\r\n");
pSocket->write("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
pSocket->write(tr("Content-Length: %1\r\n").arg(error_str.length()).toUtf8());
pSocket->write("\r\n");
pSocket->write(error_str.toUtf8());

delete pSocket;
```

Comment: You really should implement proper HTTP message framing (so consider bodies in request), check the method name, and do not send a response body for HEAD).

Comment: Also, when sending the `Content-Length` header, the value has to be the number of bytes actually being sent.  Since you are sending UTF-8 encoded strings, you have to send the number of UTF-8 bytes, not the number of string characters prior to UTF-8 encoding.  They are only 1-to-1 when dealing with ASCII characters.  If your strings contains non-ASCII characters, the string character length and encoded UTF-8 byte length will be different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could the problem be that you're not flushing and closing the socket before deleting it?

**EDIT:** George Edison answered his own question, but was kind enough to accept my answer.  Here is the code that worked for him:

```
pSocket->waitForBytesWritten();
```

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out!

After writing the data to the socket, I have to call:

```
pSocket->waitForBytesWritten();
```

...or the buffer does not get outputted.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with **telnet** or **nc** (*netcat*) to debug it.  Also, is it possible you're sending double newlines?  I'm not sure your language, so if your `print` appends a newline, switch to:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r

It's also handy to have a small logging/forwarding program for debugging socket protocols.  I don't know any offhand, but I've had one I've used for many years and it's a lifesaver when I need it.

[**Edit**]
Try using **wget** to fetch the file; use the **-S -O *file*** to save the output to a file and see what's wrong that way.

[**#2**]

> pSocket->write(error_str.toUtf8());
>
> delete pSocket;

I haven't used *Qt* for a long time, but do you need to flush or at least close the socket before deleting?

Comment: Great, install **wget** if it isn't already. You'll be glad after you start using it (if you don't already know it).

Comment: @Carter: I have `wget` installed - I'll try that.

Comment: **Aha!** "HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying."

Answer (score 0):

What you’ve shown looks okay, so it must be that you’re actually sending something different. (I presume that you're entering "http://127.0.0.1" in your browser.)

Download the crippleware version of this product and see what it reports:

http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: I tried WireShark but it wasn't showing the response my app was supposed to be making... so you might be onto something here.